# Is there a way I can filter array within another filter scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of JSON Objects then I want to check if a user search query includes in **key: names**  otherwise it will loop through **key: takers** which has array values formatted in array

By declaring a variable drugs

````
  {
  "name": "urumogi",
  "taker": ["gashuhe", "kimomo"],
  },
  {
  "name": "marijuana",
  "taker": ["karega", "kanaka"],
  },
  {
  "name": "cocaine",
  "taker": ["sigaho", "james"],
  },
  ];

const filterDrugs= drugs.filter((drug) => drug.name.includes("example drug") ? drug : drug.takers.filter(taker=> taker.includes("James")) && drug)
console.log(filterDrugs); ```
````

suppose that search query:

`let query = 'James';`

The output should be:

```
  {
  "name": "cocaine",
  "authors": ["sigaho", "James"]
}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple matches? Are you just looking for the first?

Comment: Your drugs literal has a syntax error: there is no opening `[`.  Also, your code references `taker` and `takers` property... there is only `taker`. And: you are looking for two different strings: "example drug" and "James"... Is that really what you want? And: "James" does not occur in your data -- it is "james".

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` callback return value is used as a boolean, but your first `filter` callback is always going to return a truthy value (either `drug` or else an array returned by an inner call to `filter`).

There's no need to return `drug` in that callback. Use `some` for the inner lookup, which returns a boolean, and combine that with the `includes` boolean using `||` so that you evaluate a boolean return value.

Also the capitalisation of "James" matters, and "example drug" should probably be the same string.

```js
const drugs = [{ "name": "urumogi", "taker": ["gashuhe", "kimomo"],},{"name": "marijuana","taker": ["karega", "kanaka"],},{"name": "cocaine", "taker": ["sigaho", "james"],}];

let str = "james";

const filterDrugs = drugs.filter((drug) => 
    drug.name.includes(str) || 
    drug.taker.some(taker => taker.includes(str))
);
console.log(filterDrugs);
```

Note that `filter` returns an array of matches. If instead you just want to get the first match, if any, or `undefined` otherwise, then use `find` instead of `filter`.

```js
const drugs = [{ "name": "urumogi", "taker": ["gashuhe", "kimomo"],},{"name": "marijuana","taker": ["karega", "kanaka"],},{"name": "cocaine", "taker": ["sigaho", "james"],}];

let str = "ja mes";

const findDrug = drugs.find((drug) => 
    drug.name.includes(str) || 
    drug.taker.some(taker => taker.includes(str))
);
console.log(findDrug);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should be enough to do the trick:

```
let query = 'James';
const filterDrugs= drugs.filter((drug) => {
   return drug.taker.includes(query.toLowerCase())
 })
console.log(filterDrugs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const drugs =   [
  {
    "name": "urumogi",
    "taker": ["gashuhe", "kimomo"],
  },
  {
    "name": "marijuana",
    "taker": ["karega", "kanaka"],
  },
  {
    "name": "cocaine",
    "taker": ["sigaho", "james"],
  },
];


function filterDrugs(data, query) {
    return data.filter(({ name, taker }) => name === query || taker.includes(query.toLowerCase()) )
}

console.log(filterDrugs(drugs, 'James'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply just pass your name in a function and return it with filtering you match condition

Short and sweet :)

````
  "name": "urumogi",
  "taker": ["gashuhe", "kimomo"],
  },
  {
  "name": "marijuana",
  "taker": ["karega", "kanaka"],
  },
  {
  "name": "cocaine",
  "taker": ["sigaho", "james"],
  },
  ];


function filterByName(name) {
  return (filterArr = arr.filter(item => {
    return item.name == name || item.taker.includes(name);
  }));
}

}
console.log(filterByName("cocaine"))```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-u5ktrk
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer only selects on name. The question is looking to match on taker or name.

Comment: Hi @StewartR, name is just the param or query string. my condition in the 3rd line of the function after || or operator is also return truthy or falsy 

``` item.taker.includes(name);```

please have a look here in stackbiltz https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-u5ktrk

Comment: It's better after your edit @sameer-salim

Comment: ooh oky. thanks for you feedback @stewartR

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the object into a simpler array and then search that.

Here's a working example.

```js
const drugs = [
  {
  "name": "urumogi",
  "taker": ["gashuhe", "kimomo"],
  },
  {
  "name": "marijuana",
  "taker": ["karega", "kanaka"],
  },
  {
  "name": "cocaine",
  "taker": ["sigaho", "james"],
  },
 ];
 
 function filterDrugs(searchString){
  const resultIndex = drugs.map(x => [...x.taker, x.name]).findIndex(x => x.indexOf(searchString) !== -1);
  return resultIndex !== -1 ? drugs[resultIndex] : [];
 }
 
 console.log(filterDrugs("james"));
 console.log(filterDrugs("marijuana"));
 console.log(filterDrugs("gashuhe"));
```